# how to another port setting in weblogic-maven-plugin deploy weblogic in maven

Tags: maven, deployment, weblogic-10.x, weblogic-maven-plugin

I deploying weblogic war file by maven build, and sucess adminurl to deploy weblogic

but another serverport instead adminurl how to config

weblogic have two servers  adminport(port:7001 (console) ) and serverport(8081 (server) )

I want to deploy serverport 8081 in maven build tool

how to 8081 port server deploy war file with maven plugin

my maven build source code

```
    <build>   
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupid>com.oracle.weblogic</groupid>
          <artifactid>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactid>
          <version>10.3.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
            <user>user</user>
            <password>password</password>
            <upload>true</upload>
            <action>deploy</action>
            <remote>false</remote>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <source>
${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}                </source>
            <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

how to serverport setting in maven xml tag don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can not directly do this, meaning you can directly deploy the application (war/ear) to a managed server . I guess you have a domain (so 1 admin server and 1 managed node). You have to go through the admin server.

Please read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG585).